# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION,but there is nothing in intent

Tags: android, bundle

I have a failed binder transaction error when the app quits abnormally,but there is nothing in intent. 
The images of every xml are lower than 40K,so I think it's not the problem of images.
This is my code.

```
... ...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private SlideMenu slideMenu;

static Socket socket;

private TextView titleName;
private RelativeLayout container;
private Map<String, String> mainleft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainleft = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    titleName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_bar_name);
    container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    slideMenu = (SlideMenu) findViewById(R.id.slide_menu);
    ImageView menuImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title_bar_menu_btn);
    menuImg.setOnClickListener(this);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
    String IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();  
    System.out.println("IMEI：" + IMEI);

    try {
        FragmentViewall fragment1 = new FragmentViewall(getBaseContext(),"zhuxitong.xml");
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment1).commit();
        slideMenu.closeMenu();
        titleName.setText((CharSequence) "zhuxitong");
        container.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


        InputStream input = getResources().getAssets().open("mainleftcfg.xml");
        XmlPullParser pullParser = Xml.newPullParser();
        pullParser.setInput(input, "UTF-8");
        int event = pullParser.getEventType();

        String[] temp = null;
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            switch (event)
            {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if("item".equals(pullParser.getName()))
                    {
                        temp = new String[2];
                    }

                    if ("name".equals(pullParser.getName()))
                        temp[0] = new String(pullParser.nextText());
                    if ("xmlname".equals(pullParser.getName()))
                        temp[1] = new String(pullParser.nextText());

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if("item".equals(pullParser.getName()))
                    {
                        mainleft.put(temp[0], temp[1]);
                        temp = null;
                    }

                    break;
            }
            event = pullParser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    initView();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.title_bar_menu_btn:
        if (slideMenu.isMainScreenShowing()) {
            slideMenu.openMenu();
        } else {
            slideMenu.closeMenu();
        }
        break;
    }

}


private int initView()
{
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                String serverIP = LoginActivity.socketipValue;
                String serverDK = LoginActivity.socketdkValue;
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(serverIP, Integer.parseInt(serverDK));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }.start();

    View line = new View(this);
    line.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_shelf_category_divider);
    Drawable drawable= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_category_mark2);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getMinimumWidth(), drawable.getMinimumHeight());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftq);

    Iterator iter = mainleft.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
        final String temp = (String)entry.getValue();
        final String temp2 = (String)entry.getKey();

        TextView textt = new TextView(this);
        textt.setText((CharSequence) entry.getKey());
        textt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textt.setTextSize(18);
        textt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_category_item);
        textt.setCompoundDrawables(drawable,null,null,null);

        textt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                FragmentViewall fragment1 = new FragmentViewall(getBaseContext(), temp);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment1).commit();
                slideMenu.closeMenu();
                titleName.setText((CharSequence) temp2);
                container.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });

        linearLayout.addView(textt);
    }

    TextView texttv = new TextView(this);
    texttv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.g6c1_video));
    texttv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    texttv.setTextSize(18);
    texttv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    texttv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_item_selected_bg);
    texttv.setCompoundDrawables(drawable,null,null,null);
    texttv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            videoontimeFragment fragment1 = new videoontimeFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment1).commit();
            slideMenu.closeMenu();
            titleName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.g6c1_video));
            container.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
    linearLayout.addView(texttv);

    TextView texttb = new TextView(this);
    texttb.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.g6c2_video));
    texttb.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    texttb.setTextSize(18);
    texttb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    texttb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_item_selected_bg);
    texttb.setCompoundDrawables(drawable,null,null,null);
    texttb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            videobackFragment fragment1 = new videobackFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment1).commit();
            slideMenu.closeMenu();
            titleName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.g6c2_video));
            container.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
    linearLayout.addView(texttb);

    TextView textt = new TextView(this);
    textt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.action_loginout));
    textt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textt.setTextSize(18);
    textt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_category_item);
    textt.setCompoundDrawables(drawable,null,null,null);
    textt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginActivity.sp.edit().putBoolean("AUTO_ISCHECK", false).commit();
            LoginActivity.sp.edit().clear().commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            slideMenu.closeMenu();
        }
    });
    linearLayout.addView(textt);

    TextView textt2 = new TextView(this);
    textt2.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.action_settings));
    textt2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textt2.setTextSize(18);
    textt2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textt2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_category_item);
    textt2.setCompoundDrawables(drawable,null,null,null);
    textt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(MainActivity.this);  
            builder.setMessage("1.0");    
            builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm",  
            new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                    dialog.dismiss();  
                }  
            });  
            builder.create().show(); 
            slideMenu.closeMenu();
        }
    });
    linearLayout.addView(textt2);
    return 0;
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {  
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {  
        dialog();  
        return true;  
    }  
    return true;  
}  

protected void dialog() {  
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(MainActivity.this);  
    builder.setMessage("Quit?");  
    builder.setTitle("tips");  
    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm",  
    new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            dialog.dismiss();  
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());  
        }  
    });  
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",  
    new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            dialog.dismiss();  
        }  
    });  
    builder.create().show();  
}
```

}